# Race Condition while Increasing Int from threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, int

I have a method which just increases an Integer Value (i++)

```
public void Calculate()
{
for(int i=0;i<1500;i++)
 y++;
}
```

Where Y is Int Class Variable .

```
Thread thr1 = new Thread(Calculate);
thr1.Start();   
Thread thr2 = new Thread(Calculate);
thr2.Start();
Thread thr3 = new Thread(Calculate);
thr3.Start();
Thread thr4 = new Thread(Calculate);
thr4.Start();
```

By starting 4 Threads with Calculate Delegate ,the Y Value should be 6000 ,if Y starts with Value 0
But not always it became 6000 ,Sometimes im getting 5993 or 6003 so there are cases where this value is not the one which Logically should be .
So is there any solution to prevent from that ,i dont want to Block Y while a thread is increasing ,so is there a way to set Variable Value Parallel from Multiply Threads ?

**EDIT** : It is working with `Interlock.Increment();` but it slows down the Algorithm ,so what is doing it correct and faster is :

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
{
j++;
this.label1.Text = y.ToString();
}
lock(y)
{
    y += j;
}
```

Comment: If `y += j` is inside your `Calculate` method, you will still have a race condition. Less often, but still.

Comment: @Groo check the last Update = )

Comment: You might want to share with us what your code is really trying to do; there's a good chance there's a better way.

Comment: @dlev this is a basic idea ,how can i get large amount of Pixels from Images and parallelise  the algorithm which is Single Thread one

Comment: @Cody: This will fix the race-condition, but another thing that looks strange is accessing a Control's property from a non GUI thread (actually, from several threads). Apart from the fact that `y` is constant most of the time and only changes outside the loop, this would throw a `Cross thread operation` exception (check [this link](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml), or consider using the `BackgroundWorker` component). In most cases it is better to report progress to the GUI in larger (less frequent) steps.

Comment: @Groo my ROI is the Increment Variable ,            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false; did the job for me ,so don't care about UI ,cuz UI is the next step first i need just to Logic where can i start with that Parallelism

Comment: @Cody In that case, assuming the algorithm operated on pixels independently (i.e. the result for one pixel was unrelated to the result for another pixel,) you'd be better off partitioning the image into sections, and passing those coordinates to the thread delegates. Now you don't have to have numerous synchronizations  to access a counter. Rather, you just need to synchronize the reporting of the results (e.g. by adding the result of each thread to a synchronized collection of some sort.)

Comment: @dlev thats what im thinning first thread will Handle image from Location 0,0 to image.Height/2,image.width/2 than second thread with second Portion so that's it that's the Idea cheers

Comment: @Cody: setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false doesn't fix anything, it merely disables the warning in the debugger. This is not a safe way to to threading with Windows Forms. You may get away with setting a `Text` property, but you may easily start getting very strange results. It would be better to simply remove that line, if UI is not important right now, and log to console instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a race condition. You need to use Interlocked.Increment to do this in a threadsafe manner.

Comment: Your newest version still has a race condition, it just isn't as obvious. However, now, if you use Interlocked.Increment for your `y+=j` line, you should be safe

Answer (score 2):

What you are experiencing is not loss of precision, but a result of a thread-unsafe way to access a variable. Since this variable is shared between different threads, you need to make sure that the increment operation is **atomic**. Once a thread A reads a value of a field, you must ensure that no other thread can **change it** before thread A writes the incremented value back.

To block other threads from doing this, use the [Interlocked.Increment(ref Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y114) static method to increase the value of the field atomically.

In this particular example, same results could be achieved without locking if each of your threads had its own private field to increment (you could then just add them all together at the end). You can try posting your actual code to see it can be modified in some similar way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new object y with an int value, so you can lock object y when a thread wants to increment it. This makes Calculate() threadsafe.

```
            public void Calculate()
        {                
            for(int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
            {
                lock (y)
                {
                    y.value++;
                }
            }
        }
```

> The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: The other two answers show that using a lock is *not* the only way. You may want to edit.

Comment: @dlev: well, functionally, it is fine. It is a bit slower than `Interlocked`, but it fixes the race condition.

Comment: @dlev yes Y should be Object because lock is not working with int

Comment: @dlev: Good point, this will not work. I failed to notice that `y` is passed to the `lock`.

Comment: @Groo Yeah, just noticed :) Deleted my comments since, well, they make less sense now.

Comment: Fixed that y is an object instead of value type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no threading expert, so am donning flameproof suit for this answer in anticipation of howls of protest from people who really grok threads... but wouldn't the [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) keyword do what the OP wants in this case?

From the docs:

> The volatile keyword indicates that a
>   field might be modified by multiple
>   threads that are executing at the same
>   time. Fields that are declared
>   volatile are not subject to compiler
>   optimizations that assume access by a
>   single thread. This ensures that the
>   most up-to-date value is present in
>   the field at all times.

Comment: The correct interpretation of the volatile keyword is that read and write operations to a volatile fields must not be reordered and, that the value of the variable must not be cached.

On a single x86 processor system, the only effect of the volatile keyword is that the value is never cached in something like a register and is always fetched from the memory. On a multiprocessor system, each processor has a data cache set and depending on the cache policy, an updated value for the variable might not be written back immediatly